# How to reload the page when selecting the NavLink items on reactrouter 6?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-bootstrap

Its an straightforward question how to reload the page when selecting the `<NavLink>` items on reactrouter 6? Because reactrouter 5 has `<BrowserRouter forceRefresh={true} />` to reload the page.

Below is my code and also here is the complete sandbox code [https://codesandbox.io/](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-bootstrap-offcanvas-menu-1tx0n).

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <header>
        <Navbar />
      </header>

      <main className="flex-shrink-0">
        <React.Suspense fallback={<h6>Loading...</h6>}>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
          </Routes>
        </React.Suspense>
      </main>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

any workaround or possible solutions will help.

Comment: You linked to codesandbox, generally, but missed linking to any specific sandbox. I am not sure why you'd want this behavior, but I'm sure you could use `window.reload` to accomplish this.

Comment: sandbox link have been updated.

Comment: I think Gabriele's answer below is what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a [`reloadDocument`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#link) property to the `Link` or `NavLink` that you want to cause a reload.

###### Link documentation

> You can use `<Link reloadDocument>` to skip client side routing and let the browser handle the transition normally (*as if it were an `<a href>`*).

Updated sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-bootstrap-offcanvas-menu-forked-0i4wl